# Add custom UserDetailsService to Spring Security OAuth2 app

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

How do I add the custom `UserDetailsService` below to [this Spring OAuth2 sample](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2)?

The default `user` with default `password` is defined in the [`application.properties`](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main/resources/application.properties) file of the `authserver` app.

However, I would like to add the following custom `UserDetailsService` to [the `demo` package of the `authserver` app](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main/java/demo) for testing purposes:

```
package demo;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.UserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
class Users implements UserDetailsManager {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        String password;
        List<GrantedAuthority> auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");
        if (username.equals("Samwise")) {
            auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_HOBBIT");
            password = "TheShire";
        }
        else if (username.equals("Frodo")){
            auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_HOBBIT");
            password = "MyRing";
        }
        else{throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username was not found. ");}
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, password, auth);
    }

    @Override
    public void createUser(UserDetails user) {// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(UserDetails user) {// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(String username) {// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void changePassword(String oldPassword, String newPassword) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean userExists(String username) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can see, this `UserDetailsService` is not `autowired` yet, and it purposely uses insecure passwords because it is only designed for testing purposes.

**What specific changes need to be made to [the GitHub sample app](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2) so that a user can login as `username=Samwise` with `password=TheShire`, or as `username=Frodo` with `password=MyRing`?**  Do changes need to be made to [`AuthserverApplication.java`](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main/java/demo/AuthserverApplication.java) or elsewhere?

---

**SUGGESTIONS:**

---

The [Spring OAuth2 Developer Guide](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html#grant-types) says to use a `GlobalAuthenticationManagerConfigurer` to configure a `UserDetailsService` globally.  However, googling those names produces less than helpful results.

Also, a different app that uses internal spring security INSTEAD OF OAuth uses the following syntax to hook up the `UserDetailsService`, but I am not sure how to adjust its syntax to the current OP:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Configuration
protected static class AuthenticationSecurity extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Users users;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(users);
    }
}
```

I tried using `@Autowire` inside the `OAuth2AuthorizationConfig` to connect `Users` to the `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer` as follows:

```
@Autowired//THIS IS A TEST
private Users users;//THIS IS A TEST

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
   endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter())
        .userDetailsService(users)//DetailsService)//THIS LINE IS A TEST
        ;
}
```

But the Spring Boot logs indicate that the user `Samwise` was not found, which means that the `UserDetailsService` was not successfully hooked up.  Here is the relevant excerpt from the Spring Boot logs:

```
2016-04-20 15:34:39.998 DEBUG 5535 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    :  
        User 'Samwise' not found
2016-04-20 15:34:39.998 DEBUG 5535 --- [nio-9999-exec-9]   
        w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter :  
        Authentication request failed:  
        org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException:  
        Bad credentials
```

**What else can I try?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue when developing my oauth server with Spring Security. My situation was slightly different, as I wanted to add a `UserDetailsService` to authenticate refresh tokens, but I think my solution will help you as well.

Like you, I first tried specifying the `UserDetailsService` using the `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer`, but this does not work. I'm not sure if this is a bug or by design, but the `UserDetailsService` needs to be set in the `AuthenticationManager` in order for the various oauth2 classes to find it. This worked for me:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity 
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  Users userDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
    // other stuff to configure your security
  }

}
```

I think if you changed the following starting at line 73, it may work for you:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}
```

You would also of course need to add `@Autowired Users userDetailsService;` somewhere in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

Other things I wanted to mention:

1. This may be version specific, I'm on spring-security-oauth2 2.0.12
2. I can't cite any sources for why this is the way it is, I'm not even sure if my solution is a real solution or a hack.
3. The `GlobalAuthenticationManagerConfigurer` referred to in the guide is almost certainly a typo, I can't find that string anywhere in the source code for anything in Spring.

Comment: Manan, I think I found the "global" `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` in the code. It wouldn't have occurred with that string literal, but it does with `globalAuthBuilder`. Check my posted solution below.

Answer (score 8):

My requirement was to get a database object off the back of the oauth2 email attribute.  I found this question as I assumed that I need to create a custom user details service.  Actually I need to implment the OidcUser interface and hook into that process.

Initially I thought it was the OAuth2UserService, but I've set up my AWS Cognito authentication provider so that it's open id connect..

```
//inside WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

http
.oauth2Login()
.userInfoEndpoint()
.oidcUserService(new CustomOidcUserServiceImpl());

...

public class CustomOidcUserServiceImpl implements OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> {

    private OidcUserService oidcUserService = new OidcUserService();

    @Override
    public OidcUser loadUser(OidcUserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        OidcUser oidcUser = oidcUserService.loadUser(userRequest);
        return new CustomUserPrincipal(oidcUser);
    }
}

...

public class CustomUserPrincipal implements OidcUser {

    private OidcUser oidcUser;

    //forward all calls onto the included oidcUser
}
```

The custom service is where any bespoke logic can go.
I plan on implementing `UserDetails` interface on my `CustomUserPrincipal` so that I can have different authentication mechanisms for live and test to facilitate automated ui testing.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue and originally had the same solution as Manan Mehta posted. Just recently, some version combination of spring security and spring oauth2 resulted in any attempt to refresh tokens resulting in an HTTP 500 error stating that `UserDetailsService is required` in my logs.

The relevant stack trace looks like:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: UserDetailsService is required.
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:463)
at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper.loadUserDetails(UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper.java:68)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices.refreshAccessToken(DefaultTokenServices.java:150)
```

You can see at the bottom that the `DefaultTokenServices` is attempting to refresh the token. It then calls into an `AuthenticationManager` to re-authenticate (in case the user revoked permission or the user was deleted, etc.) but this is where it all unravels. You see at the top of the stack trace that `UserDetailsServiceDelegator` is what gets the call to `loadUserByUsername` instead of my beautiful `UserDetailsService`. Even though inside my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` I set the `UserDetailsService`, there are two other `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`s. One for the `ResourceServerConfiguration` and one for the `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration` and those configurations never get the `UserDetailsService` that I set.

In tracing all the way through Spring Security to piece together what is going on, I found that there is a "local" `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` and a "global" `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` and we need to set it on the global version in order to have this information passed to these other builder contexts.

So, the solution I came up with was to get the "global" version in the same way the other contexts were getting the global version. Inside my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` I had the following:

```
@Autowired
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) {
    super.setApplicationContext(context);
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder globalAuthBuilder = context
            .getBean(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
    try {
        globalAuthBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this worked. Other contexts now had my `UserDetailsService`. I leave this here for any brave soldiers who stumble upon this minefield in the future.

Comment: This was a lifesaver. And thanks for presenting the context behind it. I wired the globalAuthBuilder.userDetailsService(..) with my userDetailsManager bean. The DefaultTokenServices is able to refresh the access tokens..

Answer (score 1):

For anyone got `UserDetailsService is required` error when doing refresh token, and you confirm you already have `UserDetailsService` bean.

try add this:

```
@Configuration
public class GlobalSecurityConfig extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public GlobalSecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

This is my try and error, maybe not work for you.

By the way, if you give up "guess" which bean will pick by spring, you can extends `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` and `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and config all stuff by yourself, but I think it's lose power of spring autoconfig.
Why I need config everything if I just need customize some config?